# WordPress REST API V2 Not Accessible with Wordpress 4.7.2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Currently, WordPress has been updated to latest version 4.7.2 while WordPress REST API V2 has not been done. So Godadday prevent from accessing my API and now I am not be able to access my API as usual and the message error shows:

> 403 Forbidden. Request forbidden by administrative rules.

So can you suggest an alternative plugin? or Can give what the good solution for is this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block of the API was only in place for a limited time on the GoDaddy Managed WordPress platform. It should have been functioning correctly for a while again. Please check.

Thanks